# DNS PTR requests for local ip addresses from proxy container

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

I have a docker setup

services:

- pihole
- squid

pi hole container is ran with `--ip 172.28.1.1`
squid container is ran with `--ip "172.28.1.2"` and `--dns "172.28.1.1"`

then some more services

- serviceOne

Service one has

```
-e HTTP_PROXY="http://172.28.1.2"
-e HTTPS_PROXY="http://172.28.1.2"
```

172.28.1.2 is the ip address of the squid container

All the containers are on the same network `--network some-network`

In pihole dns instance i'm getting logs like this.

```
2023-08-05
14:40:08    PTR 1.0.18.172.in-addr.arpa squid.pi-services   OK 
(cache) NXDOMAIN (0.1ms)
```

Why would the squid container be making dns requests for the host name of a local ip address?